# Poisson Process and dyadic numbers

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

my question is: If we have a poisson process $X=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb R_+}$ and we denote by $D$ the nonnegative dyadic numbers. Then why does

\begin{align}
P\Bigg[\bigcap_{t\in D} \bigcup\limits_{s\in D, s>t} \{ X_s=X_t \}\Bigg]=1
\end{align}

hold.

Can we use it as a limsup with Borel-Cantelli although we are dealing with dyadic numbers?

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: First step: can you prove that $$P\Bigg[\bigcup\limits_{s\in D, s>t} \{ X_s=X_t \}\Bigg]=1\ ?$$ If you prefer, do you see why $$P(\forall s\in D\ (s>t), X_s\ne X_t)=0\ ?$$

Comment: I can show, that $P(X_s-X_t \ge 1)=1-e^{-\lambda (s-t)}$ for $s>t$, but I don't know if this leads to something useful here...

Comment: What would be $$X_{t+1}(\omega)$$ for $\omega$ in the second set considered in my comment?

Comment: Since $t+1>t$, we have $X_{t+1}(\omega) \neq X_t(w)$ there.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder why you are not following my hints. Maybe read them more carefully?